# How to change storage path in laravel to resources/views?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.5, if I upload a file from a form, it will be stored in own storage directory.

Now I want to change it and want to upload file to this path: `resources/views/layouts`

Comment: Can you please share your code? It will help us to provide you a best solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think easiest solution would be:

1. create directory in storage directory with unique name, like `layouts` or so
2. create symlink from /storage/layouts to /resources/views/layouts
3. save all files you want to /storage/layouts and they will appear in /resources/views/layouts

by creating symlink I mean linux feature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems)

Comment: I want to upload file to resource, act3it blades file